# Getting factor(0) Levels: in predicting NaiveBayes model

Tags: r, predict, naivebayes

I relate to the last line in the example. I would like to build a `NaiveBayes` model per `train$TN` value. It means that for all the row that their `train$TN = 4` I'll build the `NB_TRAIN_model[[1]]`, for all rows `train$TN = 9` I'll build the `NB_TRAIN_model[[2]]` etc. However, the model will have to be based on `train$Solar.R, train$Wind, train$Temp, train$Month, train$Day` and not on `train$TN`. So, I hope I excluded this value OK by using: `Ozone ~ . -TN, data = x` (see last line):

```
   library(party)
   library(e1071)
    airq <- subset(airquality, !is.na(Ozone))
    ## split data to train and test
    set.seed(123)
    train_ind <- sample(seq_len(nrow(airq)), size = smp_size)
    train <- airq[train_ind, ]
    test <- airq[-train_ind, ]

    ct <- ctree(Ozone ~ ., data = train,  controls = ctree_control(maxsurrogate = 3))
    train$TN<-factor (ct@where)

## Builds a NB model per each terminal node
NB_TRAIN_model<-lapply(split(train, train$TN), function(x) naiveBayes(Ozone ~ . -TN, data = x))
```

Now I want to predict the values on the test. I tried to use the `model[[1]]` over the first row:

```
> predict (NB_TRAIN_model[[1]],test[1,2:6],type = "class")
```

I get:

```
   factor(0)
    Levels:
```

Comment: what package is naiveBayes from please? (also smp_size is not defined)

Comment: I use package: e1071

Comment: Thanks. Should the outcome not be discrete?

Comment: Yes. I think U R right. I changed the line: NB_TRAIN_model<-lapply(split(train, train$TN), function(x) naiveBayes(as.factor(Ozone) ~ . -TN, data = x)) to factor. Since NB can't be continuous and Ozone is continuous  value. Pitty I had no error message for this.

Comment: I think naiveBayes automatically coerces the outcome to discrete so using factor would not change it. But I think the thing to notice is that the probability tables are largely undefined -- lots of the st. deviations are NA; as there is only one value of the predictor within each class of the outcome.

Comment: So, how to fix it? Only to change to another dataset? BTW, it worked after my change.

Comment: I think you need to be careful of "it worked" - it does not make it correct. As Ozone is continuous, you should use a model that accepts a continuous outcome. Perhaps as  Bayesian net to keep to the same approach?